# Postman tests - problems with chai assertions

Tags: postman, chai

I encounter a weird problem with postman test functions.

I used to do tests like this:

```
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;
```

I needed to customize a bit so I upgraded it like this:

```
test_name = "[ "+ request.name + " ] - ";
tests[test_name + "Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;
```

This works.

I discovered recently that embedded snippet "Status code: Code is 200" would show like this:

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

Which is very nice, especially as some users have no developping background, so I tried it and decided to use it for my tests.
Then I went back to my original problem that required customization, so I did

```
pm.test(test_name + "Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

This does not work, **but it raises no error**: the test just does not appear at all in the Tests tab !

previousely I had Tests (3/3) with 3 tests with PASS, now I have Tests (2/2) (At least I would expect Tests (2/3) with one failed test or an error)

It could be my syntax, so I tried differently:

```
test_assert = test_name + "Status code is 200" 

pm.test(test_assert, function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

This doesn't work either.

to make sure nothing's wrong with my syntax I tried :

```
pm.test("[ Get all configuration - nominal ] - Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

**Which fails**. Is there a number of characters limitation ??? 
For checking purpose I tried

```
pm.test("[ Get all configuration - nominal ] - abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", function () {
```

**Which works** => it is not a number of characters limitation, so I tried setting my own string, character by character.
It works up to

```
pm.test("[ Get all configuration - nominal ] - Status code is 20", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

I end up with Tests (3/3)

**If I add the last "0" it doesn't work ????? Tests (2/2)**

I even tried :

```
pm.test("[ Get all configuration - nominal ] - Status code is 20 that's all", function () {
pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

**And it WORKS**  :(

The Tests tab indicates Tests (3/3) and I have my indication:

PASS [ Get all configuration - nominal ] - Status code is 20 that's all

Am I entreing the Twilight Zone, somehow ?

I would like to understand ... I anyone has an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to a real bug

I tried some more tests:

- to check if the problem is to end with a digit:

  ```
  pm.test("[ Get all configuration - nominal ] - Status code is 20 that's all0", function () {
  pm.response.to.have.status(200);
  ```

  });

=> it works

- to check if it is linked to the position of code 200 (I removed the final "l" of "nominal"):

  ```
  pm.test("[ Get all configuration - nomina ] - Status code is 200", function () {
  pm.response.to.have.status(200);
  });
  ```

=> it fails

- from this observation I tried inserting one or more blank spaces before "200":

  ```
  pm.test("[ Get all configuration - nominal ] - Status code is   200", function () {
  pm.response.to.have.status(200);
  });
  ```

=> it works

**whatever the number of preceding spaces before "200"**, the display in Tests tab is the following:

PASS [ Get all configuration - nominal ] - Status code is 200

**with just one space between** "is" and "200"

I think one tricky bug of the Tests tab.
**It's a real issue as, in a production cycle, it may be unnoticed**